# Formatting usb flash drive on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, usb-drive

How can I format an USB flash drive using cocoa frameworks or carbon? Is there any functions to make it?

Comment: I don't think it's fair to vote to move the question to superuser.com since the question specifically asks about Cocoa or Carbon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [diskutil](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) via NSTask. You may have to [authorize](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) the task.

Comment: hdiutil is for disk images. You may be thinking of diskutil, which is for volumes generally and for real storage devices: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html

Comment: Bah. You're right. I corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Update: Just a quick note to mention Carbon is going away *very soon* now, so the Carbon tag is probably not even a little relevant any more.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Terminal in Mac
2. Get list of disk using below command

   $ diskutil list
3. Note the name of your USB drive and enter below command

   $ sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 DISK2 MBRFormat /dev/disk2

Note : Need to enter disk name only in capital letters after FAT32 (mine is DISK2)

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the question is very specific that it was (11 years ago) looking for a programmatic solution, not a command line solution.